# Getting only the words starting with certain characters - autocomplete in jQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following code to perform an auto-completion for an input.

The problem I'm having is that with this function if I type in "En" it returns not only all the words starting with "En" (example: English, England, Enterprise, etc) but any word that contains the string of characters "En" anywhere (example: cENtral, cENtury, calENdar, etc)

What change do I need to make in my code to get only those words that start with the characters I type in?

Thanks

```
(function($){
$.fn.autoComplete = function(options){
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoComplete.defaults, options);

    // public methods
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        this.each(function(){
            var that = $(this);
            if (options == 'destroy') {
                $(window).off('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);
                that.off('blur.autocomplete focus.autocomplete keydown.autocomplete keyup.autocomplete');
                if (that.data('autocomplete'))
                    that.attr('autocomplete', that.data('autocomplete'));
                else
                    that.removeAttr('autocomplete');
                $(that.data('sc')).remove();
                that.removeData('sc').removeData('autocomplete');
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        // sc = 'suggestions container'
        that.sc = $('<div class="autocomplete-suggestions '+o.menuClass+'"></div>');
        that.data('sc', that.sc).data('autocomplete', that.attr('autocomplete'));
        that.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        that.cache = {};
        that.last_val = '';

        that.updateSC = function(resize, next){
            that.sc.css({
                top: that.offset().top + that.outerHeight(),
                left: that.offset().left,
                width: that.outerWidth()
            });
            if (!resize) {
                that.sc.show();
                if (!that.sc.maxHeight) that.sc.maxHeight = parseInt(that.sc.css('max-height'));
                if (!that.sc.suggestionHeight) that.sc.suggestionHeight = $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first().outerHeight();
                if (that.sc.suggestionHeight)
                    if (!next) that.sc.scrollTop(0);
                    else {
                        var scrTop = that.sc.scrollTop(), selTop = next.offset().top - that.sc.offset().top;
                        if (selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight - that.sc.maxHeight > 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight + scrTop - that.sc.maxHeight);
                        else if (selTop < 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + scrTop);
                    }
            }
        }
        $(window).on('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);

        that.sc.appendTo('body');

        that.sc.on('mouseleave', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mouseenter', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mousedown click', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (e){
            var item = $(this), v = item.data('val');
            if (v || item.hasClass('autocomplete-suggestion')) { // else outside click
                that.val(v);
                o.onSelect(e, v, item);
                that.sc.hide();
            }
            return false;
        });

        that.on('blur.autocomplete', function(){
            try { over_sb = $('.autocomplete-suggestions:hover').length; } catch(e){ over_sb = 0; } // IE7 fix :hover
            if (!over_sb) {
                that.last_val = that.val();
                that.sc.hide();
                setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 350); // hide suggestions on fast input
            } else if (!that.is(':focus')) setTimeout(function(){ that.focus(); }, 20);
        });

        if (!o.minChars) that.on('focus.autocomplete', function(){ that.last_val = '\n'; that.trigger('keyup.autocomplete'); });

        function suggest(data){
            var val = that.val();
            that.cache[val] = data;
            if (data.length && val.length >= o.minChars) {
                var s = '';
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) s += o.renderItem(data[i], val);
                that.sc.html(s);
                that.updateSC(0);
            }
            else
                that.sc.hide();
        }

        that.on('keydown.autocomplete', function(e){
            // down (40), up (38)
            if ((e.which == 40 || e.which == 38) && that.sc.html()) {
                var next, sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (!sel.length) {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first() : $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).last();
                    that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val'));
                } else {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? sel.next('.autocomplete-suggestion') : sel.prev('.autocomplete-suggestion');
                    if (next.length) { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val')); }
                    else { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(that.last_val); next = 0; }
                }
                that.updateSC(0, next);
                return false;
            }
            // esc
            else if (e.which == 27) that.val(that.last_val).sc.hide();
            // enter or tab
            else if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 9) {
                var sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (sel.length && that.sc.is(':visible')) { o.onSelect(e, sel.data('val'), sel); setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 20); }
            }
        });

        that.on('keyup.autocomplete', function(e){
            if (!~$.inArray(e.which, [13, 27, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40])) {
                var val = that.val();
                if (val.length >= o.minChars) {
                    if (val != that.last_val) {
                        that.last_val = val;
                        clearTimeout(that.timer);
                        if (o.cache) {
                            if (val in that.cache) { suggest(that.cache[val]); return; }
                            // no requests if previous suggestions were empty
                            for (var i=1; i<val.length-o.minChars; i++) {
                                var part = val.slice(0, val.length-i);
                                if (part in that.cache && !that.cache[part].length) { suggest([]); return; }
                            }
                        }
                        that.timer = setTimeout(function(){ o.source(val, suggest) }, o.delay);
                    }
                } else {
                    that.last_val = val;
                    that.sc.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

$.fn.autoComplete.defaults = {
    source: 0,
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 150,
    cache: 1,
    menuClass: '',
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
};
}(jQuery));
```

**UPDATE**

So I have a input like:

```
<input id="searchword" autofocus type="search" name="search" placeholder="Introduce word" >
```

and script that call the autoComplete jsquery included above and in the same file I have the PHP that gets the list of words:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.auto-complete.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#searchword').autoComplete({
            minChars: 2,
            source: function(term, suggest){
                term = term.toLowerCase();
                var choices = [<?= $list ?>];
                var suggestions = [];
                for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                    if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                suggest(suggestions);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

PHP code that gets the list of words from my DataBase:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

   $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM words";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    $get_total_rows = pg_numrows($result);
    $i =  $get_total_rows; 

while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $word = $myrow[word];
    if ($i == $get_total_rows){
        $list = "'" . $word . "'";
        $i = $i -1;
    }
    else {$list = $list . ", '" . $word . "'";} 
     }

?>
```

Comment: Are u getting your results from db?

Comment: Because if you have a query you can change it from like to select name from tablesname where name like 'En%'

Comment: @LearningPhase  Yes I'm but I don't know how to pass it. Please see the update of original post.

Comment: please see the answer below.

Comment: Did the below answer help you?\

Answer (score 0):

```
$termfilter = $_GET['term']; you pass this in from your page
```

Use the below query to search with like keyword

SELECT * FROM words
WHERE your field name LIKE '$termfilter%';

Comment: Did the above suggestion help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm trying to figure out where exactly to use it because the only query I have is to get the words from database and it is not recursive (meaning it doesn't change depending on the typing)   I'm not following either where and how to use: `$termfilter = $_GET['term'];`  Thank you so much